# Craft CMS combining element-api and Simple Map plugin

Tags: php, plugins

I've been using element-api for simple lazy-loading of things like blog posts, etc and now want to create a simple 'Postcode lookup' by utilising a custom filter (provided by the Simple Map plugin).

Simple Map provides a custom field that uses the Google Maps API for address data and geolocation.

My question is this: How would I call the custom Simple Map filter using the 'criteria' settings in element-api so that I can pass through a postcode (via a javascript call to the api/customer-search.json?postcode=M25ND) and return results based on the custom field filter?

I'm using Craft 3:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "craftcms/cms": "^3.0.0-RC1",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4.0",
    "roave/security-advisories": "dev-master",
    "craftcms/redactor": "1.0.0.1",
    "craftcms/element-api": "^2.5",
    "ether/simplemap": "^3.1"
},
```

**element-api**
https://github.com/craftcms/element-api

**simple map** https://github.com/ethercreative/simplemap

The below will return entries that are within 100 miles of the location provided:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.map({
    location: 'M2 5ND',
    country: 'GB',
    radius: 100,
    unit: 'mi'
}).orderBy('distance').all() %}
```

.. and the simple look up in my element-api.php file currently returns all 'customer' entries:

```
<?php

namespace Craft;

use craft\elements\Entry;

// https://github.com/ethercreative/simplemap
// https://github.com/craftcms/element-api

return [
    'defaults' => [
        'elementType' => Entry::class,
        'elementsPerPage' => 9,
        'pageParam' => 'pg',
        'resourceKey' => 'entries',
        'transformer' => function(Entry $entry) {
            return [
                'id' => $entry->id,
                'title' => $entry->title,
                'url' => $entry->url,
                'map' => $entry->map,
            ];
        },
    ],
    'endpoints' => [
        'api/customer-search.json' => [
            'criteria' => [
                'section' => 'customers',
                'type' => 'customer',
                // how to include map({}) filtering of results?
            ],
        ],
    ]
];
```

What I'm struggling to do is combine the two. As far as I can tell; element-api criteria only works with the parameters listed here: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries

Thanks in advance for any direction you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

It should work the same way because the `modifyElementsQuery` should be fired no matter where the `ElementQuery` object is build so you could insert the same array in your element-api endpoint as you insert in your `CraftVariables` `entries` function to  build the [EntryQuery](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/elements/db/EntryQuery.php) since they both use [Yiis configure](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/BaseYii.php#L543) function to build the

```
'endpoints' => [
    'api/customer-search.json' => [
        'criteria' => [
            'map' => [
                'location' => 'M2 5ND',
                'country' => 'GB',
                'radius' =>  100,
                'unit' => 'mi'
            ],
            'orderBy' => 'distance'
        ],
    ],
]
```

should theoretically build the same object like

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.map({
    location: 'M2 5ND',
    country: 'GB',
    radius: 100,
    unit: 'mi'
}).orderBy('distance') %}
```